# fit-content property override other properties in grid

Tags: html, css

I've setup a grid with the following:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 120px auto fit-content auto;
```

Why is the first column, which defined to be `120px` width is override?
As I see the resulted grid, the width of the first column is not `120px` but more..

Comment: the whole value become invalid because fit-content() is an invalid value

Comment: @TemaniAfif EDITED

Comment: no, fit-content() need to take an argument to be valid like fit-content(10%). check the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns